# How to mount HFS+ rEFInd partition as boot in Arch Linux

Tags: partition, startup, high-sierra, dual-boot, efi

I am currently trying to set up dual boot on my Mac. I installed rEFInd to its own partition (512MB), formatted as "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)". I wanted to use the same partition as my boot partition under linux. But every time I pacstrap my system, I get an error message stating that "/mnt/boot is mounted as read-only". It's probably because it can only read the mounted partition based on the filesystem I used.
I read that installing it on the existing EFI partition has caused some problems for other people so I wanted to go and take the "safe route".

I want to use rEFInd to start my OS', I do not really care if it shows up on the Startup Manager provided by Apple. I just want to be able to boot into OS X if something happens and goes horribly wrong :)

Is using FAT32 as the formatting a good idea? It would allow me to mount is as rw and make it usable as my boot partition. Or how do you guys have installed rEFInd on your systems?

Comment: Generally, Linux can not write to a "Mac OS Extended" partition unless journaling is turned off.

Comment: @David That's the thing. As of disk utility, journaling is actually turned off. I disabled it under the file menu. But it still shows up as being enables in the filesystem for odd reasons.

Answer (score 2):

For those that might have similar questions/problems. You have to explicitly disable journaling using `diskutil` on the command line. Using `Disk Utility.app` does not work properly.

Comment: It is not that the Disk Utility does work properly. Actually, the Disk Utility used to have the ability to turn off journaling. Apple removed this feature a few mountains ago.

Comment: It still has it, at least the menu entry. That's the thing. I clicked on the menu entry: 'Disable Journaling'. But is literally does nothing